# How to pass parameter from node child process to execute commands in batch file?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, child-process

I need to put all the commands in a batch file (test.cmd) with some logic, for example:

```
IF condition1 (c:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /Create ...)
Else (c:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /delete ...)
```

If remove the if-else statement, and only leave one command in test.cmd, by using code like this can execute the command:

```
exec('some-path/test.cmd', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
```

If add if-else statement back, does anyone know how can I pass parameter from node.js exec() function? In the terminal, it is easy to pass parameters like "test.cmd para1".

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use node spawn. 
Example variables

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I did it by using exec() in Node.js.